# Read data from a multi separated csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file into R. The problem is that the file has 2 separators and I don't know how to read it as a 3-column data frame;i.e first, second, and year.
This is a sample of how the file looks like:

```
[Alin Deutsch, Mary F. Fernandez, 1998],  
[Alin Deutsch, Daniela Florescu, 1998],
```

I've tried the `fread()` function with `sep="["` and `sep2=","`, but it does not work and R just read it the row as 1 column vector
Thanks

Comment: Use sed or awk or ... to remove the `[` before importing to R?

Comment: Are those functions embedded into R?

Comment: No, those are (powerful and fast) command line text editors. You can call them from within R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) read.table/sub** Read it in using `sep = ","` and `comment.char = "]"`.  That will split the fields and get rid of the trailing `]` and everything after it and then we can just remove the `[` from `V1` with `sub`:

```
Lines <- "[Alin Deutsch, Mary F. Fernandez, 1998],  
[Alin Deutsch, Daniela Florescu, 1998],"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",", comment.char = "]", as.is = TRUE,
          strip.white = TRUE, # might not need this one
          col.names = c("Name1", "Name2", "Year"))
DF <- transform(DF, Name1 = sub("[", "", Name1, fixed = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
> DF
         Name1             Name2 Year
1 Alin Deutsch Mary F. Fernandez 1998
2 Alin Deutsch  Daniela Florescu 1998
```

**2) read.pattern**  Another possibliity is to use `read.pattern` in gsubfn.  This pattern assumes that each line begins with [, has three commas with the last one having a ] before it.  That corresponds to what is in the question but if that is not the case the regular expression would need to be changed.

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = ".(.*?),(.*?),(.*?).,", as.is = TRUE,
        strip.white = TRUE, # might not need this one
        col.names = c("Name1", "Name2", "Year"))
```

giving the same.

Comment: I've done this, and it works for text data, but doesn't work for the csv file. It still reads it as one column

Comment: If you are referring to (2), as stated in the answer if your actual data deviates from that shown in the question then the pattern will have to be modified appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

You could read the file with `sep=","` and then remove the extra brackets:

```
df <- read.csv(file = textConnection("[Alin Deutsch, Mary F. Fernandez, 1998],  
[Alin Deutsch, Daniela Florescu, 1998],"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE,head=FALSE)

df <- df[,-4]

df$V1 <- gsub("\\[","",df$V1)
df$V3 <- gsub("\\]","",df$V3)

names(df) <- c("first","second","year")
df
```

output

```
         first             second  year
1 Alin Deutsch  Mary F. Fernandez  1998
2 Alin Deutsch   Daniela Florescu  1998
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this solution and it works.

First, I removed "[" and "]" from the file using `gsub`

```
clean <- function(x){
gsub("\\[|\\]","",x)  
}

sample_clean <- sapply(sample,clean)
head(sample_clean)
```

Then, I split the column vector into 3 coumns using `str_split_fixed`

```
data <- str_split_fixed(sample_clean,",",3)
```